# Let H = ⟨R n ⟩. Show that H is normal in D2n.

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let n ∈ Z≥2, and let D2n be the symmetry group of a regular 2n-gon. Recall that
D2n = {I, R, R^2, . . . , R^2n−1, F, RF, R^2F, . . . , R^(2n−1)F} and F R = R^(2n−1)F.
Let H = ⟨Rn⟩. Show that H is normal in D2n.

Work: I know if I just plug in values its normal but I don't know how to show it arbitrarily in a proof.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, this question is about the dihedral group of order $4n$.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* Assuming you mean $H = \langle R^n \rangle$, prove that $FR^nF^{-1}=R^n$, using $FRF^{-1}=R^{-1}$.